# MSBuild - Project Dependencies Build Order Anomaly

Tags: msbuild, dependencies

We have an MSBuild `.proj` file that is used to build and run lots of projects. That have file references to one another. Due to the fact that it is file references, we maintain the list of Project Dependencies on the solution, so that MSBuild is able to identify the order to execute projects in.

We had an issue recently, where our US development team added a new reference to one project, but didn't update the dependencies list. This builds fine for them locally, and on the server. However for the UK team, the build consistently failed for all developers.

I'm trying to understand why this was the case. The only thing I can think of is that our Culture causes the build order to be slightly different when two projects are essentially ranked at the same level. i.e. If Project A and B are perceived to have the same dependencies, then the order the two build in is arbitrarily determined, and this might be different in the UK culture vs the US culture.

That said, my machine (it broke for me) has the Region Format set the English US. And Location UK.

Does this sound feasible? or is there a better explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the culture will not fix the issue where you're making a file reference on a components output rather than a project reference to the project that will build the assembly.

Solution files do map dependencies and would help MsBuild determine build order.  When MsBuild processes a solution it will first convert it in memory to MsBuild xml format, then it will determine project order by listing the dependencies, then determine if a project needs to be rebuilt by comparing the last update time of the input files to the output files.

When you have a project reference within a project (in a project, open the References folder, remove references to output assemblies and instead reference the project itself).  This will modify the project file replacing Reference item groups with ProjectReference item groups.  This allows MsBuild to make this determination on a project level and resolves the issue of having to manually configure the project build order.

Comment: Unfortunately, for a variety of reasons, Project references are generally not used in our solution. We have hundreds of projects, normally opened using different solutions to the build Soln - Projects in one of these solutions use project refs but refs between sections use file refs.

Comment: So if project A is dependent upon the output of project B but uses a file reference rather than a project reference, you won't know if you have the most recent code from project B at compile time.  This is just some plumbing you can add to make your life easier.  I've had to do this in the past on solutions comprising > 100 projects.  It does seem like a daunting task, but will save you a lot of grief by no longer clinging to a faulty paradigm :)

Comment: Our builds are configured to wipe the slate clean and start from scratch on every build, so that's not a major concern. I'd love to switch to incremental, but I believe the company has been bitten by it in the past, so want to remain on full clean builds. I believe the switch to file references is because we use smaller more focused solutions for development - project refs like to try to remove themselves when you remove them from the solution.

Comment: What sort of unit testing strategy does your team use, and how long are the full build times?  Having to wait four minutes to determine if your code change had an impact on your unit tests would be a concern that would drive an initiative to support incremental builds :)

Comment: With SSDs the build is 4 minutes or so. Without they can take about 20 minutes. Unit tests are sparse, but being pushed more recently. However, that is beyond my control, and not the focus of the immediate issue. Whilst I'd love to make the change, I simply can't. I need to understand *why* the build failed here but not over the pond with the same files.

Comment: On that you should get one of the US folks to make a diagnostic MsBuild log and compare that to one of yours, then post the relevant outputs for the failing targets.